# 500 - Internal server error when use webapi controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I add webapi controller  to project , of course  for handle webapi methods path I use below code inside `WebApiConfig.cs` into **App_Start** folder:

```
public static class WebApiConfig        {
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
       {
           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
       }
   }
```

and this line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

into **Global.asax**  such as below code :

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Now project run currently in **localhost** but in server get error :

> Server Error
>
> 500 - Internal server error.
>
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
> I restart app in IIS and restart IIS but don't solve.

How to fix this?

**Update1:**
I log IIS errors by *failed request tracking rules* and get logs.Logs are such as this image :

[image]

I searched the main error in tabs but don't found it.

What message is general error ?

Comment: Enable "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" to break on any unhanded exception, You should be able to locate the issue.

Comment: You can get the detailed error by adding the following in config file:     <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>

Comment: check the server logs to find what the exception was, or temporarily enable detailed error reporting as suggested by Vineet. The 500 error is just a generic HTTP status code indicating a server-side crash, designed deliberately not to give away any details which might compromise the server. You have to go and find the underlying error which caused the crash. Once you find it, post it here if you don't understand how to resolve it. Also post any code referenced in its stack trace which may be relevant.

Comment: @PSK how can i Enable "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

Comment: @Vineet Desai  don't solve

Comment: @programmer138200 check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Comment: @programmer138200 you should also show the code for the action you are trying to call.

Comment: @Nkosi  :  In this case no need , because all request for server get 500 error code

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered specifically.

Comment: I suggest you move your codes to ASP Core WebApi (without MVC). Error like this isn't happening there and that was the solution I applied when i faced it.